# How to extend an interface of extended class

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use the latest typescript and reactjs versions together and have a problem with extended classes and the extension of its interfaces.

For several form elements (all have the same validation methods) i have created a BaseComponent which looks like this:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import React = require('react');

interface P {
    id: string
    onChange: Function
    error: string
}

interface S {
    value: string
    isValid: boolean
}

class BaseComponent extends React.Component<P, S> {
    protected isValid(value) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

export default BaseComponent;
```

And the Component which extends from the BaseComponent:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
import React = require('react');
import BaseComponent from './baseComponent';

interface P {
    id: string
    onChange: Function
    error: string
    required?: boolean
}

interface S {
    value: string
    isValid: boolean
    somethingNew: string
}

class NameFieldContainer extends BaseComponent {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: '',
            isValid: false,
            somethingNew: 'Foo'
        };

        this.aMethod();
    }

    protected aMethod() {
        this.setState({somethingNew: 'Bar'});
    }

    public render() {
        const somethingNew = this.state.somethingNew;
        return (
            <div>{somethingNew}</div>
        );
}

export default NameFieldContainer;
```

Now my compiler (and IDE) show some problems with the new state.somethingNew and props.required properties. I have no idea how to extends this. How can I teach the BaseComponent that he have to use the Interfaces from the NameFieldContainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to extend your existing interfaces for the props and state. Your `BaseContainer` would look like this

```
class BaseContainer<PP, SS> extends React.Component<P & PP, S & SS> {

}
```

and your concrete implementation of that you would use

```
interface PExtended {
    id: string
    onChange: Function
    error: string
    required?: boolean
}

interface SExtended {
    value: string
    isValid: boolean
    somethingNew: string
}

class NameFieldContainer extends BaseContainer<PExtended, SExtended> {...}
```

You also have to keep in mind if the state fields are not optional (by declaring it as `value?:string`) you have to set them in `setState({})`.